# at.js can't use remote filter no drop-down displayed

Tags: php, jquery

I've been trying to implement @mentions for my php application using the At.js library in version 1.5.1 from https://github.com/ichord/At.js

When i typing @ and something after, i see an ajax query in firebug, but i don't see the drop-down to select the differents names.

My javascript code used is the following :

```
$('#editor').atwho({
    at: "@",
    displayTpl:"<li data-value='${key}'>${username} <img src='${avatar}' height='20' width='20' /></li>",
    callbacks: {
        remoteFilter: function(query, callback) {
        if(query.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: $( "#url_mentions" ).val(),
                    data: {
                        search : query
                    },
                    done: function(data) {
                        callback(data.users);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The json which is returned by calling the url directly in browser :

```
{"users":[{"key":"[mention userid=742]admin[\/mention]","userid":"1742","username":"admin","avatar":"<img class=\"kavatar\" src=\"http:\/\/jfconnectoquickstart\/media\/tr\/avatars\/resized\/size24\/cs\/s_nophoto.png\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"  alt=\"admin's Avatar\" \/>"},{"key":"[mention userid=743]jack[\/mention]","userid":"743","username":"jack","avatar":"<img class=\"kavatar\" src=\"http:\/\/jfconnectoquickstart\/media\/tr\/avatars\/resized\/size24\/cs\/s_nophoto.png\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"  alt=\"jack's Avatar\" \/>"}]}
```

The HTML part :

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Message</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea class="span12" name="message" id="editor" rows="12" tabindex="7"
              required="required"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do-you have an idea to fix it ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Did you try to console.log query before the ajax request? I think you're sending the @... Which is probably should be removed.

Comment: @user3533235 have the same problem did you get it working ?

Answer (score 1):

Little late but might help others.

You must add "searchKey" parameters (see the first parameter)

```
$('#editor').atwho({
searchKey: 'username', // this is what missing
at: "@",
displayTpl:"<li data-value='${key}'>${username} <img src='${avatar}' height='20' width='20' /></li>",
callbacks: {
    remoteFilter: function(query, callback) {
    if(query.length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $( "#url_mentions" ).val(),
                data: {
                    search : query
                },
                done: function(data) {
                    callback(data.users);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

});